# How can I prove that I did a review for a journal?

Tags: journals, review-articles, elsevier

About two years ago, I did a review for a journal (Engineering Failure Analysis, which is published by Elsevier). At that time my affiliation was different from today and I used my institutional email at that time to register as a reviewer in the Elsevier website. But right now that email is deleted and I don't have access to that email. I need to show somewhere that I did a review for this journal and they need some evidence. Despite, I have access to my account in Elsevier (The email is deleted but the account in Elsevier website remained unchanged and I have access to it), I can't find their acknowledgment email for my review. I asked their editorial office and their editor-in-chief 3 times and still after about 1 month I didn't get any answer yet. So, basically I want to know is it enough to take screen capture and show that I did the review to proof or not? Cause in some websites like [Publons](https://publons.com/home/), it needs to send the confirmation email to their email server to be able to put it in your webpage and count it as a review, but I don't have that confirmation email and I don't think I could get that due to they're ignoring my emails. Any idea, suggestion, and recommendation is appreciated.

Also if somebody knows some sort of customer service or front desk information for Elsevier, I will appreciate if he/she could give it to me cause maybe it could be helpful to contact them directly. I searched a lot in their website but I didn't find anything about how to contact them.

Comment: I'm afraid what counts as proof depends on who is demanding the proof.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo it’s one of the US government agencies, which probably people there are not academic experts (It’s not a funding agency like NSF or NIH).

Comment: I think only the people demanding the proof can answer this question - there is no universal (or near universal) standard.

Comment: With security investigations and background checks, there’s no onus on you to prove your claims. The onus is entirely on NBIB to do a thorough investigation, and any details you provide beyond what is on the SF-86 are a voluntary disclosure that you are (legally) not obligated to provide. Of course, providing the information up front will accelerate the process and may reflect favorably on you (such as admitting to a history of drug use rather than hiding it).

Comment: I hope you’re able to settle this, but I do think that it is outside the scope of this site and have voted to close. I am a USG research contractor and am happy to talk further about explaining academia to govvies/the clearance process if you reach out via email (see my profile) or chat.

Comment: @StellaBiderman What?! What security or background check you guys are referring to?! No, you got it wrong. Let’s say there is an agency which wants to give me a benefit but it needs to prove your research accomplishments by showing that you judged the work of other people. That’s it. There is no security or background check or whatever and also I want to get that review confirmation cause it reinforce my application to get that benefit.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer You were vague about what the particular need for this was. One potential source of this question would be if you were having a (re)investigation. In case that was the source, I provided some additional info. At the time I wrote that comment, something had suggested to me that that might be the reason, though I’m blanking on what that would have been now...

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Is it possible that this information is listed on the journal website or front matter somewhere? In CS, it is common to thank reviewers by name.

Comment: @StellaBiderman no I rejected that paper :)

Comment: I don't understand. If you turned them down for a review, what do you hope to achieve here? There's no prestige in *not doing work*.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I think the OP means they did the work of peer reviewing the paper, but advised the journal to reject it.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I did the review but I advised the editor to reject it. As a result, my name is nowhere to be acknowledged.

Comment: Does anyone know if Elsevier has any sort of customer service or front desk or something like that which might be helpful to call them and ask them if they could send me an email about that review?

Comment: In CS, it is common to acknowledge reviewers _even for rejected papers_ by listing them in the front matter of the journal/proceedings.  Presumably your review was anonymous to the authors, so even if the paper was accepted, you wouldn't find proof f your review in the paper.

Comment: I am curious why you need to prove that you did the review. Perhaps it is not relevant to the question, but perhaps explaining that might give the opportunity for answers that might better help your root need. I am curious because I have never needed to PROVE that I did a peer review. If I have claimed to do so, it has never been questioned. If you have a compelling reason, then sharing that with the editorial office or editor in chief might make them give your inquiries greater priority.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask the editorial office. You write that you've already asked them, but send them a reminder. Tell explicitly what you're looking for. In my experience for example, a letter saying you performed a review, on official Elsevier letterhead paper & with the desk editor's signature, suffices. This really should be something the journal office can do quickly. If they haven't responded my guess is that they're waiting for the editor-in-chief to respond, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Much like during a background check, you can't provide more evidence than you have access to. (Well, you could, but it's generally frowned upon.) So send in what you have and let them judge it. Perhaps they don't consider it proof enough, which I assume means that you don't get credit for that one review, but no worse consequences than that.

Answer (score 4):

Check whether an issue of the journal lists you as a reviewer and if it does, then use that issue as evidence.

Comment: I advised to reject that paper so that paper was not published to put my name as a reviewer in that issue.

Comment: Your recommendation doesn't matter: Many journals acknowledge reviewers (regardless of their recommendation---doing otherwise would be a little peculiar). When acceptance is recommended, the acknowledgement shouldn't appear in the same issue, since that would comprise anonymity.

Comment: Good answer. See for example: https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ecy.2072

Comment: Unfortunately, this journal particularly in the Elsevier does not have any acknowledgment page for reviewers...

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Just to clarify, I mean an acknowledgements page in an issue of the journal, rather than a web page listing names. (The link provided by Emilie looks like it is a page from such an issue.)

Comment: @AloneProgrammer it's a bummer that this exact journal does not do that. Let's hope this answer will help someone else with the same issue.

Comment: @Emilie The Elsevier website is just a crap. At least I could not find it. I searched in Google but it just shows me the other journals of Elsevier but not this one. Crazy...

Comment: @AloneProgrammer I did a small research to look if there was a "reviewer acknowledgement" articles for your journal, but I don't think it exist

Comment: @Emilie Thank you for your help! I think it's better to stick to Editor-In-Chief or other editors maybe at least one of them give me an answer hopefully...